# MongoDB: export JSON containing date strings to ISOdate object using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to export the json file with ISOdate() in mongoDB document. But I am unable to find how to convert date string to ISOdate in json, so that I can import it to mongo document

This is the json I have and I want to convert the `lastSyncedAt` into ISOdate object

```
[{"_id": "123", "lastSyncedAt": "2021-03-10T15:46:51"}]
```

```
[{"_id": "123", "lastSyncedAt": ISOdate("2021-03-10T15:46:51")}]
```

Comment: You may be better served exporting in [MongoDB Extended JSON (v2) relaxed format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date).  I.e., `"lastSyncedAt": {"$date": "2021-03-10T15:46:51"}`

Answer (score 2):

To do this in pymongo, use the [json_util](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html) module. Export with `dumps` and import with `loads`.

```
import datetime
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycoll.insert_one({"_id": "123", "lastSyncedAt": datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2021-03-10T15:46:51")})
print(dumps(db.mycoll.find()))
```

prints:

```
[{"_id": "123", "lastSyncedAt": {"$date": "2021-03-10T15:46:51Z"}}]
```

Comment: Actually, I cannot connect to mongoDb and cannot fire this query. All I can do this is to export/import file.

Comment: I had a problem when converting to json I wanted to preserve the date.time to use it and save it to Mongo in other collections : `formisoformat()` is what i need it!
thanks